# Postgresql Geometric Line - Finding the Y intercept

Tags: postgresql, geometry

I have an model that can be represented by multiple linear segments as below:

```
 Y
  |   _/_________\_
  |   /           \
  |  /             \
  | /               \
  |/                 \
  |           
  |________________________ X
```

I would need to find the value of Y for a given value of X

My initial though was to store each segment as a relational `line` type {A, B, C}. However I'm not sure what would that buy me in terms of finding a proper query to retrieve the Y value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working with linear segments, you should use the `lseg` data type (the `line` data type represents a line of infinite length). Once you have your data in that format you can find the intersection of the segments with a vertical line of infinite length at the desired value of X and extract the Y value of the intersection.

```
CREATE TABLE segments (id int, seg lseg);

INSERT INTO segments VALUES 
  (1, '[(4,3), (12,15)]'),  -- positively inclined line segment
  (2, '[(2,19), (24,-4)]'), -- negatively inclined line segment
  (3, '[(4,3), (12,3)]'),   -- horizontal line segment
  (4, '[(5,3), (5,15)]'),   -- vertical line segment, collinear at X=5
  (5, '[(4,3), (4,15)]');   -- vertical line segment, no intersection at X=5
```

and then:

```
test=# SELECT id, 5 AS x, (seg # '((5,-999999999), (5,999999999))'::lseg)[1] AS y
test-# FROM segments;
 id | x |        y
----+---+------------------
  1 | 5 |              4.5
  2 | 5 | 15.8636363636364
  3 | 5 |                3
  4 | 5 |
  5 | 5 |
(5 rows)
```

As is obvious from the above, collinear line segments (i.e. vertical line segments with the same value for X) and segments without intersection return `NULL` for Y.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick : This is very helpful. Given the lseg, I've tried using `path` instead to represent multiple segments (and as it more aligned with the model). However it doesn't look like intersection operation `#` is defined for path (which is a bit strange).  Is it possible to type case path into multiple segments?

Comment: I have not worked with the `path` type so I can't tell. My background in GIS does tell me that the data types and operations are a fairly limited set of the analysis techniques in graphing and geography. Perhaps you can use the PostGIS extension (a `path` would be a `geometry(LINESTRING)`) with its extended set of analysis operations?